# When I use Rules in Scrapy Spider It gives Invalid Syntax error for the following function

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am building this spider in scrapy , python 3.0. The problems is that whenever i use rules, it gives an error "Invalid syntax" for def parse_productPage. When i remove the rules it doesn't complain and works fine. I cannot find what's wrong with the code. Can you please help me. Here is the code

```
import scrapy
from quo.items import QuoItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class ISpider(CrawlSpider):
    name='iShopE'
    allowed_domains = ['ishopping.pk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ishopping.pk/electronics/home-theatres.html']
    rules = (
                Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div["category-products-"]'), follow=True),
                Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//h2[@class="product-name"]/a/@href'), callback='parse_productPage'),
    )


    def parse_productPage(self,response):
      for rev in response.xpath('//div["product-essential"]'):
        item=QuoItem()
        price=response.xpath('//div[@class="price-box"]/span[@class="regular-price"]/meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content').extract()
        if price:
            item['price']=price
        Availability=response.xpath('//p[@class="availability in-stock"]/span[@class="value"]/text()').extract()
        if Availability:
            item['Availability']=Availability
        Brand=response.xpath('(//div[@class="box-p-attr"]/span)[1]/text()').extract()
        if Brand:
            item['Brand']=Brand
        deliveryTime=response.xpath('(//div[@class="box-p-attr"]/span)[2]/text()').extract()
        if deliveryTime:
            item['deliveryTime']=deliveryTime
        Waranty=response.xpath('(//div[@class="box-p-attr"]/span)[3]/text()').extract()
        if Waranty:
            item['Waranty']=Waranty

        yield item
```

Here is the output log[Output log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9enD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike what the error message shows, the problem is actually in the lines before:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div["category-products-"]'), follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//h2[@class="product-name"]/a/@href'), callback='parse_productPage'),
)
```

If you carefully count the parentheses here, you can see that there are three opening parentheses but only two closing for each rule:

```
Rule(
    LinkExtractor(
        restrict_xpaths=('//div["category-products-"]'),
        follow=True
    )
```

So to fix this, just add a closing parenthesis for each `Rule` there:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div["category-products-"]'), follow=True)),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//h2[@class="product-name"]/a/@href'), callback='parse_productPage')),
)
```